# Edit Text to String Not Saving What's Typed

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, gettext

After extensively trying to figure out why my SharedPreferences are always blank, or never created. I have concluded that it is because the edit text to string isn't doing anything, yet I have no idea why it isn't doing anything.

Here is the code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Friday extends Fragment{


    private String GBand, BBand, ADV1Band, ADV2Band, CBand, FBand;

    @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);



        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friday, container, false);

        TextView GValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bandText111111);
        GValue.setText( "G Band" );

        EditText GEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText111111);
        GBand = GEdit.getText().toString();

        TextView BValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bandText222222);
        BValue.setText( "B Band" );

        EditText BEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText222222);
        BBand = BEdit.getText().toString();

        TextView ADV1Value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bandText333333);
        ADV1Value.setText( "Advisory 1" );

        EditText ADV1Edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText333333);
        ADV1Band = ADV1Edit.getText().toString();

        TextView ADV2Value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bandText444444);
        ADV2Value.setText( "Advisory 2" );

        EditText ADV2Edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText444444);
        ADV2Band = ADV2Edit.getText().toString();

        TextView CValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bandText555555);
        CValue.setText( "C Band" );

        EditText CEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText555555);
        CBand = CEdit.getText().toString();

        TextView FValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bandText666666);
        FValue.setText( "F Band" );

        EditText FEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText666666);
        FBand = FEdit.getText().toString();




        return view;



    }
               public class EditTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

                   private final TextView target;

                   private EditTextWatcher(TextView target) {
                       this.target = target;
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                       this.target.setText(s);
                   }


                   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
                         Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
                      inflater.inflate(R.menu.android_apply, menu);
                   }

               }

               public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
                          // Handle presses on the action bar items
                          switch (item.getItemId()) {
                              case R.id.apply:

                               SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("schedule",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                                editor.putString("g_Friday", GBand);
                                editor.putString("b_Friday", BBand);
                                editor.putString("adv1_Friday", ADV1Band);
                                editor.putString("adv2_Friday", ADV2Band);
                                editor.putString("c_Friday", CBand);
                                editor.putString("f_Friday", FBand);
                                editor.commit();



                                  Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                                  startActivity(in);

                                  return true;



                          }
                        return true;

               }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a close look at what you are doing there:

- You're retrieving the value of the `EditText` when you *create* the view. By default, the `EditText`s should be *empty* then.
- You then take those empty values and store them to shared preferences *later* on.
- When you store the values, you are not actually retrieving the values from the `EditText`s -- you are simply using the empty values you retrieved in the beginning.
- Your TextWatcher is not attached to anything.

Side note: Java coding conventions usually call for lower-case identifiers for variables, and upper-case identifiers only for classes, interfaces, etc. To a seasoned Java developer, your code will be somewhat unreadable.

To fix it, follow this pattern (shown only for GBand):

- Ditch the `private String...` members and declare `private EditText edtGBand;`
- in `onCreateView()`, include `edtGBand = (EditText) view.findViewById( R.id.editText1111111 );`
- in your `onOptionsItemSelected`, use `editor.putString( "g_Friday", edtGBand.getText().toString() );`

Comment: No, I'm saying you should access the EditText's actual contents when you write your SharedPreferences. If you assign the value to a String in the beginning (as you were), then that value won't change when you update the EditText. You'll retrieve the value when you need it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say move it out of the oncreate. I must have been thinking about edittext when I wrote that. Thank you though for your helpful answer, tested it an it seems to work.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Try making the edittexts protected and adding the line "string" = "edittext".getText().toString(); inside afterTextChanged()